# issue a single git command to pull or rebase all derived branches from the parent branch?

Tags: git

In git, I have one parent branch p and several branches based on p called a, b, c. I want to rebase a, b, and c on an updated p in a single git command. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your .gitconfig:

```
massrebase = "!sh -c 'for branch in $@; do git rebase $0 $branch; done;'"
```

and then

```
git massrebase p a b c
```

Comment: Thanks @colin. I put it in the alias section and it works great.[alias]
        massrebase = "!sh -c 'for branch in $@; do git rebase $0 $branch; done;'"

Comment: Be careful with that though, it could go really badly (and you will have to know about the reflogs to sort everything out).

Comment: Right, I assume you mean if a, b, and c aren't children of p, then rebase will blindly go and do what are potentially some very strange and destructive things.

Comment: Yes, or if there are conflicts you will have to handle that properly